# Couldn't get the location of the image

Tags: java, android

```java
package com.example.locationfinder;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.drew.imaging.ImageMetadataReader;
import com.drew.imaging.ImageProcessingException;
import com.drew.lang.GeoLocation;
import com.drew.metadata.Directory;
import com.drew.metadata.Metadata;
import com.drew.metadata.Tag;
import com.drew.metadata.exif.GpsDirectory;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String[] permissions = {"android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"};
    private final int GALLERY_REQ_CODE = 1000;
    ImageView imgGallery;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        requestPermissions(permissions,80);
        imgGallery = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Button btnGallery = findViewById(R.id.button);
        btnGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent iGallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                iGallery.setData(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(iGallery,GALLERY_REQ_CODE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        ImageView imgGallery = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        assert data != null;
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        InputStream inputStream;
        try {
            assert uri != null;
            inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQ_CODE) {
                imgGallery.setImageURI(uri);
            }
        }
        Metadata metadata;
        try {
            metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(inputStream);
        } catch (ImageProcessingException | IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        for (Directory directory : metadata.getDirectories()) {
            for (Tag tag : directory.getTags()) {
                System.out.println(tag);
            }
        }
        GpsDirectory gpsDirectory = metadata.getFirstDirectoryOfType(GpsDirectory.class);
        GeoLocation geoLocation =  gpsDirectory.getGeoLocation();
    }
}
```

after adding the `GpsDirectory` and `GeoLocation` the app keeps getting crashed and the logcat showed this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.drew.lang.GeoLocation com.drew.metadata.exif.GpsDirectory.getGeoLocation()' on a null object reference
```

The app was working fine
I could select and change the image and also the tags were printed but in the tags the location attributes longitude and latitude was not included
but I wanted that and then tried to use the gps directory and then the app started crashing

Comment: There error states you are trying to invoke a method on a null object. Have you checked if gpsDirectory is not null?